# Has any one managed to use Sound BlasterX AE-5 on ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, soundcard, sound-blaster

Is there a driver for the Sound BlasterX AE-5?

How would i install [these patches](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Sound-BlasterX-AE-5-Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out!!!!
Tested on Ubunbtu 20.04LTS as well
-Select your soundcard using Alsamixer
-Very right select HP/Speak